# PHPUnit, Zend Framework 2 Getting Started tutorial, WAMP and git

Tags: git, windows-7, phpunit, wamp, zend-framework2

I'm following the ["Getting Started" tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/overview.html) and I'm stuck on the Unit Testing part. I used git to install phpunit by opening a Git Bash command prompt and typing:

```
cd C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit.git
```

I see in the directory that the files are there. `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3` is in my Path environment variables. I created the directories and files as required by the tutorial. When I open a Git Bash command prompt and type:

```
cd C:/wamp/www/ZendSkeletonApplication/module/Application\test
phpunit
```

I get the error `sh.exe": phpunit: command not found`.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** I added `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\phpunit` to my include_path in php.ini and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: You can find the `phpunit.bat` file in `%phpdir%/phpunit/` not in `%phpdir%`

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, my `phpunit.bat` file is located in `C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/phpunit` so I opened a Git Bash command prompt and typed 
`cd C:/wamp/www/ZendSkeletonApplication/module/Application/test` 
`C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/phpunit/phpunit.bat phpunit`
and I got a bunch of errors.

Comment: These are the errors: 
    `C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/phpunit/phpunit.bat: line 1: @echo: command not found` 
    `C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/phpunit/phpunit.bat: line 2: REM: command not found`
    `C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/phpunit/phpunit.bat: line 3: REM: command not found`
    `C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/phpunit/phpunit.bat: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token '('`
    `C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.3/phpunit/phpunit.bat: line 4: 'REM Copyright (c) 2002-2010, Sebastian Bergmann <sebastian@phpunit.de>.'`

Comment: As you can tell, I have very little command prompt experience. I just want to get coding... Where is an IT person when you need one (for free)?

Comment: Are you sure you're running phpunit.bat with the Windows Command Prompt?  That seems to be the sort of response MinGW or Cygwin would give. Try running `php phpunit/phpunit.php`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run this stuff in the git shell – that’s wrong. Unless you understand what’s going on, only run git stuff in the git shell. Press <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and enter `cmd`. Try again there.

Comment: Thanks. Took your advice and I'm getting `'"@php_bin@"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` error. I'm totally lost. I thought if I put the path to php in my system environment path variable, I could run commands like `php phpunit/phpunit.php` but I am getting the error `'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`. `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3` is in my path environment variable.

Comment: Are you sure it is? Run `echo  %PATH%` to confirm.